# Memory leak caused by Dojo 1.7.2 in IE8

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-8, dojo

We have a developed a rich web application using Dojo (using many different views, lots of buttons, events between views etc.). Any data is loaded asynchronous via Rest interfaces.

Now we realized that in Internet Explorer 8 the footprint of our application is huge and grows if the URL to the application is opened within the same tab/browser window twice or more times the footprint grows and soon causes an out of memory.

It seems that Dojo does not disconnect any event handlers/DOM nodes.

I tracked this down to a simple html page with only a single Dojo button widget and analyzed the html page with sIEve (memory leak analyzer for IE8). If the html page is called again, some DOM nodes are not released (become orphans).

Is there any setting/trick/pattern to prevent orphans?

I think that this behaviour causes the huge footprint of our Dojo application which is not released when leaving the application URL.

This is the sample html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MemLeak Test</title>
    <style>
        @import "../themes/claro/claro.css";
    </style>
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        data-dojo-config="'parseOnLoad':true"
        src="../js/dojo-release/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require([ "dojo/parser" ]);
        require([ "dijit/form/Button" ]);
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <h1>Memory Leak?</h1>
    <input
        type="button"
        dojoType="dijit.form.Button"
        label="Button"></input>
</body>
```

After opening the sample html file twice in sIEve, it reports already 18 orphaned items:
HEAD, SCRIPT, DIV, SPAN (repeated in different orders); all with only 1 Ref and marked as leak!; 
(Sorry, I cannot post any screenshots)

Thx for any help on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never destroy these widgets and thus the browser keeps in memory all the references to events, dom nodes etc.
You can partially solve the problem using the unload event listener and there call the destroy method of the widget you created.

Here is an example:

```
require(['dojo/_base/unload', 'dojo/_base/array'], function(unload, array){
    unload.addOnUnload(function(){
        array.forEach(myWidgets, function(wgt){
            wgt.destroy();
        });
    });
});
```

or, in case you don't have a reference to your widgets, you can iterate over the dijit registry:

```
require(['dojo/_base/unload', 'dojo/_base/array', 'dijit/registry'], function(unload, array, dijitRegistry){
    unload.addOnUnload(function(){
        array.forEach(dijitRegistry.toArray(), function(wgt){
            wgt.destroy();
        });
    });
});
```